# Shortest path in an adjacency list in non-weighted graph

Tags: java, algorithm, shortest-path, adjacency-list

First, I would like to make sure I got the structure correct.
As far as I know, an adjacency list representing a graph looks like this:

[image: an adjacent list]

AdjList is an ArrayList, where each element is an object. Each object contains an ArrayList inside to represent vertices connected. So for example, in the image above, Vertext 1 (first index in the AdjList) is connected to the vertex at index 2, 4, and 5 of the AdjList. Is this representation of an adjacency list correct? (ps: I know indices start at 0, i put 1 here for simplicity/ease).

If it is correct, which algorithm should I use to find the shortest path between two vertices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no algorithm to give you just the shortest path between two vertices. You can use either:

1. [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) to find the shortest path between one vertex and all the others (and then choose the one you need).
2. [Roy-Floyd algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) to find the shortest path between all possible pairs of vertices.

The links also include pseudocode.

Comment: For unweighted graph Dijkstra is an overkill. You can just use BFS and stop at first moment you reach destination.

Comment: Furthermore, reading on Dijkstra's alg, it seems like the graph has to be weighted?

Comment: @lyrae: You can simply set all the weights to 1 if your graph is non-weighted.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example for [Dijkstra's shortest path](http://renaud.waldura.com/doc/java/dijkstra/) algorithm in java along with explanations

Answer (score 1):

You can use Dijkstra's and Floyd Warshall. For unweighed graph assume weight of each edge to be 1 and apply the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Previous answers mention disjktra and floyd algorithms to resolve the problem and are valid solutions, but where the graph is unweighted, the best solution is use a [BFS](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/breadth-first-search-or-bfs-for-a-graph/) technique, simpler and optimal.

BFS has a algorithm complexity of O(n), while disjktra O(n * log(n)) and Floyd O(n^2)

Comment: Well, the goal is expose the technique to resolve the problem raised, is general, so I proposed one general solution(as anothers answers), the link is only one site where it's explained the technique, but you can find reference in a lot of sites